# Marker eventListener fails to give me the object I request

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am doing an app where when I click on a marker on a google.map triggers some action, specifically I want to get an object out of an array of objects to display the details of such object.

I use the controller defs like so

```
(function() {
 'use strict';

angular
   .module('gulpAngular')
   .controller('GeolocationController', GeolocationController);

/** @ngInject */
function GeolocationController(HouseList) {
....
}
})();
```

The HouseList is a service defined elsewhere and having a method called getHouses()

Inside my controller, I do besides other things this:

```
var vm = this;
vm.houses = HouseList.getHouses();
```

Then I define my marker on the map like

```
allMarkers = new google.maps.Marker({....});
```

and add an Listener to it like below. To make things simple, I assign vm.house = vm.houses[0]

```
allMarkers.addListener('click', function() {
    vm.house = vm.houses[0]
}
```

Now I suppose I should be able to use the vm.house object to display in my html block the attributes of this house object in the fashion of

```
<h4>{{vm.house.bedrooms}}</h4>
```

HOWEVER, NOTHING GETS DISPLAYED. I should see my vm.house object be updated and this reflected on the DOM, correct? What do I miss?

Funny: When i add a simple button on the html and use a ng-click function on it without anything other than say console.log(vm.house), not only it does display the correct object, but also the refresh of the html is happening. I am lost

thanks
Peter

Comment: So it looks like you are using the contollerAs syntax, how are you attaching your controller to your html template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addListener` is not an Angular function and will not trigger the digest loop. You need to do it manually.

For example:

```
allMarkers.addListener('click', function() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        vm.house = vm.houses[0]
    });
});
```

Note that you need to inject `$scope` for this.

`ng-click` triggers the digest loop, which is why using it will update the HTML.

Comment: Just for the sake to completely understand. I said that when I simply add a button and use the ng-click to actually do nothing related, it worked fine. Is this because the ng-click does natively launch the $scope.$apply() ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can see exactly what it does here if you are curious: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L69